# How to use clamp CSS to adjust font size while keeping it aligned to a paper like css grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to make a responsive text section which has a paper like horizontal line grid and the text aligned properly on the grid.

I can achieve that if font size is not changing. I am wondering if this possible to do with plain css only or do I need to use JavaScript.

I am attaching two codepen where one is showing desired output with a fixed font size while other is showing a way to achieve the same effect with clamp css property. I have got something but it doesn't always align to the grid.

The code snippet below is what I have in the codepen which is trying to achieve the grid alignment while using css grid -

```
:root{
  --fs:clamp(2rem, 4vw , 5rem);
}

.paper{
  position: relative; 
}

.paper h2 { 
  font-size:var(--fs);
  line-height:calc(var(--fs) + 0.05rem);
}

.paper:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute; 
  overflow:hidden;
  top:calc(-2*var(--fs) - 0.65rem);
  left:-10%;
  width:120%;
  height: 170%;
  z-index:-1;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    transparent 0rem, 
    transparent calc(var(--fs) + 0.1rem), 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.2) calc(var(--fs) + 0.2rem)
    );
}
```

[CodePen with Fixed font size](https://codepen.io/yumelabs/pen/WNWNQKw?editors=1100)

[CodePen with Clamp CSS](https://codepen.io/yumelabs/pen/RwOPxmw?editors=0100)

Is there a better approach to get the same effect? CSS way or javascript way?

Comment: I don't see how you can mix vw and rem units and get a consistent result. Could you describe why both are used?

Comment: This what I have seen in most of the tutorial for clamp() css. Basically, you set font size based on viewport width and set min and max value to it.

Comment: Yes, I'm happy with the clamp to set the font-size, but once that is defined, I am not happy with the mixing of it and rem in the other calculations.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: I'd calculare everything in terms of the font-size rather than mix it with rems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `lh` unit. Here is a simplified example. You need to make sure the `font-size` is applied to the element (or a parent of it) where you will be using `lh`.

```css
h2 { 
  font-size: clamp(2rem, 4vw , 5rem);
  line-height: calc(100% + .1rem);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    #0000 0 calc(1lh - .1em), /* 1em = line thickness */
    red 0 1lh);
}
```

```html
   <h2 class="text-4xl"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit pariatur laudantium, placeat dolores veritatis impedit autem fuga ea eos sequi?   </h2>

   <h2 class="text-4xl">Qommodi facere, corrupti quibusdam quasi ad nihil sit? Numquam vitae temporibus corrupti. Odio modi quos, doloribus aliquam accusantium iusto officia temporibus, vitae harum eius ducimus nemo. Aspernatur ut dolore expedita voluptas eligendi tempora?</h2>
```

If you want a full screen solution use border-image like below:

```css
h2 {  
  font-size: clamp(2rem, 4vw , 5rem);
  line-height: calc(100% + .1rem);
  border-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    #0000 0 calc(1lh - .1em), /* 1em = line thickness */
    red 0 1lh) fill 0//0 100vw ;
    
    
  margin-inline: max(1rem,50% - 400px);
}
```

```html
<h2 class="text-4xl"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit pariatur laudantium, placeat dolores veritatis impedit autem fuga ea eos sequi?   </h2>

   <h2 class="text-4xl">Qommodi facere, corrupti quibusdam quasi ad nihil sit? Numquam vitae temporibus corrupti. Odio modi quos, doloribus aliquam accusantium iusto officia temporibus, vitae harum eius ducimus nemo. Aspernatur ut dolore expedita voluptas eligendi tempora?</h2>
```

Comment: This is an amazing solution. Loved the simplicity and implementation. The only drawback   I see is that the lines are not are not full width. But I loved you suggestion to use use unit  lh. Let me try.

Comment: @BLΛCK added another idea